# Run php with cron in a container

Tags: php, docker, cron, containers

I'm trying to run a php file with cron inside a container.

I already tested with an "echo" directly in cron and it worked.

If I try to run the php file in the console, it also works.

I just can't seem to run a php file, I request your help.

I have tested several solutions I found on the internet without success.

Thanks

**crontab**

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/html/index.php
#Empty Line
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:8.2-apache

COPY index.php  /var/www/html/

ADD crontab /etc/cron.d/hello-cron
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/hello-cron

RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

RUN apt update
RUN apt install cron -y

CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
$crontext = "Cron Run at ".date("r")." by ".$_SERVER['USER']."\n" ;
$folder = substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'],0,strrpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'],"/")+1);
$filename = $folder."cron_test.txt" ;
$fp = fopen($filename,"a") or die("Open error!");
fwrite($fp, $crontext) or die("Write error!");
fclose($fp);
echo "Wrote to ".$filename."\n\n" ;
?>
```